# nav bar won't display horizontally when fully expanded in the browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my nav bar to display `horizontally` in a line at the top of my web page below my `h1` tag. I tried all sorts of different methods to get it to line up horizontally but it won't change. My nav bar continues to display `vertically` centered. I want it to be a thin bar up at the top below the `h1`. As of right now, it displays with each `li` stacked on top of the other instead of side by side. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

```css
#wrapper{   
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #000066;
        min-width: 700px; 
        max-width: 1024px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-top: 0px;
        }

h1 {
        background-color: darkcyan;
        color: #74ebd5;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 80%;
        padding: 30px;
        text-shadow: #CCCCCC;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        }

main {
        margin-left: 180px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
        }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    }
li a {
   display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav{    display:inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: grey;
        }
 nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid ;
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
}
nav a{
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 100%
        } 
nav a:link{color:cyan;}
nav a:visited{color:#6699FF;}
nav a:hover{color: gold;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Polar Bar</h1>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="social.html">Social</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `li` elements `inline-block`, and add `box-sizing:border-box`:

```css
CSS: #wrapper {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000066;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  color: #74ebd5;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 80%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-shadow: #CCCCCC;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

main {
  margin-left: 180px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: grey;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a:link {
  color: cyan;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: #6699FF;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Polar Bar</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="social.html">Social</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Genius, pure genius. Thank you very much for your help. Upvote and check for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. what did you want?.But Is this you want?

```css
#wrapper{   background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #000066;
        min-width: 700px; 
        max-width: 1024px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        padding-top: 0px;
        }

h1 {background-color: darkcyan;
        color: #74ebd5;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 80%;
        padding: 30px;
        text-shadow: #CCCCCC;
        margin-bottom: 0;}

main {margin-left: 180px;

        padding-bottom: 100px;
        }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 98% !important;

}



li a {


   display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



nav{    display:inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: grey;
        }

 nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav a{text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid;
      } 




nav a:link{color:cyan;
}
nav a:visited{color:#6699FF;}
nav a:hover{color: gold;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Polar Bar</h1>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="social.html">Social</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
  </header>
</div>
```